# How to reset Dropdown Select List so it displays placeholder after the value was selected

Tags: react-native, expo

In my React Native Expo project I wanted to add a button that would reset Dropdown Select List.
So when I select some value from the list and press the button, I want the placeholder to be displayed instead of previously chosen value.
Is there any way to do that?

So far I was able to change the value to null with useState but still previous value was displayed instead of placeholder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.